# How to make these sentences passive: 'People believe that Jenkins is the culprit.' and 'People believed that Jenkins was the culprit.'

Tags: tenses, passive-voice, infinitives, time

How to make these sentences passive? *'People believe that Jenkins was the culprit.'*  and *'People believed that Jenkins was the culprit.'*

I know it is

> Jenkins is believed to have been the culprit.

and

> Jenkins was believed to be the culprit.

How come the same tense in the object clause 'that Jenkins **was** the culprit' becomes different infinitives – 'to have been' versus 'to be'?

Comment: In the passive forms, only #1 needs to differentiate between the present and the past that the active already did. Also, "It is now believed that Jenkins was the culprit," not that it's pretty.

Comment: @YosefBaskin So you do not look at the tense in the subordinate clause only but at the time relationship between the verb in the main clause and the verb in the subordinate clause: same time period = simple infinitive; subordinate action or state pre-dating main one = perfect infinitive

Comment: So far as I know, "passive" here simply means that the subject / agent is unspecified. So there's also *It **is / was believed** that he **is / was** guilty*.

Comment: These are complex sentences; they contain several clauses. Which clause is sposta be changed into passive? And what if the clause is intransitive, like Jenkins being the culprit? Obviously the question was posed by someone who doesn't understand English grammar.

Answer (score 1):

It is to do with the time difference between the act and the belief.

**When the crime occurred (in May 2005) Jenkins was believed to be the culprit.**

**Following a long investigation which lasted two years, in 2007 Jenkins was believed to have been the culprit.**

**More questions were raised by a 2009 investigation but following the recent discovery of further information Jenkins is (now) believed to have been the culprit.**

Comment: That seems to be on the right lines, @Nemo. But also, _after Jenkins dies_ we can say either he "was (once) believed to have been the culprit" or he "is (still) believed to have been the culprit." If the case is now forgotten we'd say the first, otherwise the second. It's surprisingly tricky, this question!